# How to trim values in application.properties in the Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

In the application.properties of the Spring Boot project, I have the following property.

```
spring.config.import=vault://apps/tam/api/${spring.profiles.active}
```

from the env I am getting the value of Spring.profiles.active is preview-15 but I need only preview in the variable.

Comment: why? if that's not the profile active? you can always 'trim' it in your code

Comment: Is it possible to trim in the application.properties only ?

Comment: what you are talking about is not "trimming". Trimming is deleting trailing spaces. "-15" are not trailing spaces.

Comment: No. the application.properties is just a file specifying properties that spring reads in. Its not code. If you were to use SpEL inside your actual code (`@Value`) to substring the value of the property, that could work.